# Nant Task For IlMerge 2.9.210.0

Tags: nant, ilmerge

Anyone know where I can get a Nant task for ILMerge 2.9.210? I have tried this http://code.google.com/p/ilmerge-tasks/ but it is built against ILMerge 2.0.7.28 of ILMerge. It says that the new project is at ilmerge.xpdm.us (sorry new user, can't post 2 hyperlinks) but that link doesn't seem to work for me. Anyone got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`'ILMerge'` [these tips](http://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/archive/2009/11/11/ilmerge-as-nant-task.aspx) with [these tips.](http://blogs.geekdojo.net/rcase/archive/2005/01/06/5971.aspx).

Basically - create a new nant task.

Worked fine for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

ILMerge Tasks for NAnt & MSBuild can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/ilmerge-tasks/